# Знаки препинания в предложении: "Играй пока молодой"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении? То есть правильно "Играй, пока молодой" или "Играй пока молодой"?

Answer (score 4):

> …нужна ли запятая в предложении ***Играй пока молодой***?

**Нужна.** Запятая позволяет правильно прочитать это предложение.

Сравните варианты:

***Играй, пока молодой.***

***Играй пока, молодой.***

Comment: А если будет такое предложение: "Играй, пока молод", то запятую нужно ставить и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Играй, пока (ты) молодой.**

Запятая ставится, например, в похожем тексте известной песни (танцуй, пока молодой). http://webkind.ru/text/2969684_52310p73612572_text_pesni_tancuj_poka_molodoj_malchik.html

Нет причин, чтобы не поставить запятую. Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным времени, запятая ставится перед союзом ПОКА.

Главное предложение ― односоставное, придаточное предложение ― неполное, в нем пропущено подлежащее.